# mex function fill mxCreateDoubleMatrix MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, mex

I have those lines of code:

```
cam::intStruct image = de->get_image ();
int i, j;
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(320, 120, mxREAL);
memcpy(image.arr, plhs[0], 320 * 120 * sizeof(double));
```

and Im trying to fill *plhs[0]* with image content, but as result i get all 0 values in output (*plhs[0]*).

```
struct intStruct 
{
    int arr[320][120];
};
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fill plhs[0] with the image content.
That means, plhs[0] is the destination and image arr is the source.

If this is the case then I think memcpy should be changed as follows.

first get a pointer to plhs[0],

```
double *ptr = (double *)mxGetData(plhs[0]);
```

then do the memcpy on this pointer.

```
memcpy(ptr, image.arr, 320 * 120 * sizeof(double));
```

Comment: works like charm, thank you. Another question, if i change size i.e. 640*240 matlab crashes again, its because of memory?

Comment: Glad to hear that :).
640 * 240 double, should be around 600 kb, that does not sound like memory problem to me considering it is a small memory in general.

Did you change size at both the calls, i.e. 
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(640, 240 , mxREAL);
and
memcpy(ptr, image.arr, 640* 240 * sizeof(double));
??

Comment: Yes, i changed at both calls, but i guess a problem stands at my header file. Im trying to get raw and undistorted Leap motion images to matlab, but on 640x240 it crashes Matlab, meanwhile in Visual Studio using openCV works perfect